# Mongo - query selector based on value of 3rd element in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a bunch of documents in my Mongo collection that have the following form:

```
{
    name: 'Some Name',
    price: 1.40,
    settings: [
        { version: 'A'},
        { version: 'C'},
        { version: 'A'},
        { version: 'B'},
        { version: 'B'},
        { version: 'C'}
    ]  
}
```

I want to return all documents in which the third elements in the settings array has version = 'C'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB query forms support ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) in which you can specify the "position" of the element you want to look for:

```js
db.collection.find({ "settings.2.version": "C" })
```

That is based on the `0` index being the first element in the array and so on.

So the third element in `n-1`.